# Number guessing game always returns the same output

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm making a simple number guessing game from 1 - 10 using an if...else statement, it worked the first time, but it seems it always outputs "You didn't guess it correctly." when I'm guessing or the other way around. Would be great for some help, so here are the solutions I made as of asking this question:

```
//This is the first solution I've come up with.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
  int guessingNumber = '5';
  printf("Guess from 1-10: ");
  scanf("%d", &guessingNumber);

  if (guessingNumber == true) {
    printf("You guessed it!\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("You didn't guess it correctly.\n");
  }
  return 0;
}


//Here is the second one.
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int guessingNumber = '5';
  int guess;
  printf("Guess from 1-10: ");
  scanf("%d", &guess);

  if (guessingNumber == guess) {
    printf("You guessed it!\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("You didn't guess it correctly.\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I'm sure that the problem causing this is in this lines from the first solution:

```
printf("Guess from 1-10: ");
      scanf("%d", &guessingNumber);
    
      if (guessingNumber == true) {
        printf("You guessed it!\n");
```

and this from the second solution that I'm sure the problem (might also) came:

```
printf("Guess from 1-10: ");
  scanf("%d", &guess);

  if (guessingNumber == guess) {
    printf("You guessed it!\n");
```

Comment: `int guessingNumber = '5';` You are using a `char` here. It should be `int guessingNumber = 5;`

Comment: To clarify the second one works right away if you remove the `'`''s. Those are used to mean "give me the integer (eg ascii) value of this character", rather than the numerical value 5.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks for the quick answer! I do reckon that I did this earlier, but it worked now. I guess I was just confused, thank you again!

Comment: @yhrycanus Oh, so that's what it does, I'm just confused so I didn't know what to do. Thanks for the information though!

Answer (score 0):

The comparison is unsafe int and a bool. Check the following.

```
int main()
{
    int actualNumber, guessingNumber = 5;
    printf("Guess from 1-10: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &actualNumber);

    if (guessingNumber == actualNumber) {
        printf("You guessed it!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("You didn't guess it correctly.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```